# React Material UI createTheme_default is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I have created a project using vite and react. I create a theme to set my project into right to left.
Everything was ok and the project was running properly.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl' , 
  typography: {
    "fontFamily": `"iransans"`,
    "fontSize": 11,
    "fontWeightLight": 300,
    "fontWeightRegular": 400,
    "fontWeightMedium": 500
   }
})
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin]
})


function App() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let contained = "Test The";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Route exact path="/applicant">
                  <Applicant />
                </Route>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </CacheProvider>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

After I add a Slide component to my project. Suddenly my project stop working and the console is showing the

> Box.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: createTheme_default is not a function
> at Box.js:5:22

I rollback my changes(by git checking). but the error is still showing.

I can't understand what's going on
Why is the error still there after reverting the changes?

Comment: whitch version o material ui you are using ?

Comment: "@mui/material": "^5.10.14",

Comment: the error looks like it has no thing to do with the **App component** it says in  `Box.js`

Comment: could it be possible that in exchange to Vite's blazing fast compilation speed, you get a pretty poor dependencies handling...???

Comment: Sometimes the question include its answer. When error is exist after rolling back the git . it means that something occurs on git ignored files. the error specially in .vite file.

Answer (score 30):

Not using ThemeProvider just plain MUI. I found that the error was coming from my app.tsx page where I import CSSBaseline.

Moving CSSBaseline above Box import on first page solve the issue:

From:

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
```

To:

```
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
```

Comment: Wow! Of all the solutions, this worked for me!

Comment: Put `import Box from '@mui/material/Box';` after other mui components worked for me (e.g. after `import Button from '@mui/material/Button';`)

Comment: Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Amazing that this was the solution

Comment: vite sucks... never happens with webpack

Answer (score 26):

I've discovered there is a problem with the Vite cache, try running your development command with the --force flag to fix the cache issues:

> yarn dev --force

or with npm

> npm run dev --force

Comment: This solution was helpful, thanks.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me

Comment: very helpful, thanks my king =)

Comment: I like vitejs but i have had difficulties working with react mui components and after removing the components for some reason the ERROR remain there. Thanks that help me to continue with my job.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by removing the node_modules/.vite/deps folder and restarting the server.

Comment: This worked for me without any issue. Thanks

Comment: now getting Outdated Optimize Dep

Comment: Thank pal, in a vitejs project its works fine. `rm -rf node_modules/.vite/deps` and then `npm run dev`

Answer (score 12):

For me it was because of imports of MUI `Box` component:

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { BoxProps } from '@mui/material/Box/Box';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

I changed it to

```
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { BoxProps } from '@mui/material';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material';
```

And it worked

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error so I removed all material ui dependency and reinstalled them, it worked for me.

```
yarn remove @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

or

```
npm uninstall @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Comment: This was the solution for me ! +1

Answer (score 5):

The main error is due to not getting the availability of the theme provider before accessing the components, or, in other cases, a vite-cache issue.

To solve the first case, wrap you App component inside theme provider.

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
   direction: 'rtl',
   // other theme properties
});

function App() {
   return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div className="App">
             ...
          </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
   )
};
```

Now in case of second problem, restart your server with `--force` flag.

For ex: `npm run dev --force`

Answer (score 5):

Had the same bug.
Cause:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

Solution:

```
import createTheme from "@mui/material/styles/createTheme";
```

Comment: The only proper and correct answer after searching a lot on google and stackoverflow

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the first option causes this bug?

Comment: What's the reason this bug is caused @SukhdevsinhZala , if you know?

Answer (score 3):

As other people say, fixing the import in `App.tsx` fixed the issue, at least for me.

**Before** (Here I get `ThemeProvider` and `createTheme` from `@mui/material`):

```
import { Container, CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";
```

**After** (Correctly imported from `@mui/material/styles`):

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles"
import { Container, CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
```

You can see how the people from Material UI import this element in their [Troubleshooting page](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/troubleshooting/).

Another thing, the order of imports also matters, so ThemeProvider and createTheme should be before any other element that uses them.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Non of the above fix my error, for me changing the import of CssBaseline did the trick.
I had this import:

```
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'
```

and change it to:

```
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'
```

and that fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

1. node_modules
   -> .vite (delete this file)
2. New install `npm install vite`
3. For yarn `yarn add vite`

Answer (score 1):

> 

I think this is given inside the index.js not in App.js
We give Routes in App.js only not the Providers

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But this solution didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Need to shift your Provider code from here to some other file and then attached it here.

Comment: I did it. but the problem was not solved. I  remove the matiral ui and install it again and them problem have been solved.

Comment: Then it might have a compatibility issue. Great your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had been getting the same error in my project... I tried npm run dev --force to delete MUI version cached in Vite (as suggested)... I checked all imports (import Box from ...) to be (import { Box } from...)...

But then, I realized that I might have placed wrongfully the Engine provider and Theme Provider. In my case, I was using suspense, and the Wrapper tags of the providers were wrapping the Component outside the Suspense tag.
That was enabling a function before it already exists, hence causing that error.

I moved the Providers inside the Suspense, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by simply downgrading the mui. This version works in my case.

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.7"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the imports

import {ThemeProvider} from '@emotion/react'-

import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material'+

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The fix for me was to make sure `ThemeProvider` was imported before Box. Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the theme provider import in my App.jsx file fixed it for me.

Previously:
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";

Now:
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

Answer (score 1):

Your components should have a correact import path:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

It's doesn't work

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, styled } from '@mui/material';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove node_modules and install again, and restart your app

Comment: There is no need to delete all node_modules. As SOURVE mentioned, .vite file must be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed it by removing the node_modules folder my the project and then reinstalled it by using npm install

Answer (score 1):

delete .vite (build cache folder inside node_modules) and restart the dev server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by delete node_modules and then re install
its perfectly working!

Answer (score 0):

I have reasons to believe that this problem originates in the `@mui/icons-material` package, if you follow [this issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/31835), which is still open as I'm writing this.

The issue has indeed been solved after I removed the `@mui/icons-material` dependency from my project.

You can still use material icons in your project by importing them through the [Icon component](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#icon-font-icons) instead of [Material SVG icons](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#material-svg-icons).

More specifically, add this to your **index.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

And instead of this:

```
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
    
<AddIcon />
```

Use this:

```
import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';

<Icon>add</Icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Vite, my easy solution was run vite with --force option.

`npm run dev -- --force`

or

`yarn run dev -- --force`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same bug and this fixed it for me too:

```js
import createTheme from "@mui/material/styles/createTheme";
```

Instead of this

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved it doing the following steps:

1. open `node_modules/@mui/material/Box/Box.js`
2. remove line 5: `const defaultTheme = createTheme();`
3. remove line 7: `defaultTheme,`
4. restart `yarn dev --force`