# createTheme_default is not a function at box.js material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, material-ui, inertiajs

I'm trying to use text field from material ui and I use Box element and i got an error message saying that there is an error in box.js. Box.js is a built in file from material and i can't change it. Here's my component codes. I don't understand why the error is in box.js. How can i fix it?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import styled from "styled-components";
import Layout from '../../Layouts/SideMenu';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';


const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
`;


export default function Create() {
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Wrapper>
                <form action="">
                    <Stack spacing={3} direction="column">
                        <h2>Form Tambah Siswa</h2>

                        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Nama" variant="outlined" />
                        
                        <Box
                            component="form"
                            sx={{
                                '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                            }}
                            noValidate
                            autoComplete="off"
                            >
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Email" variant="outlined" />
                        </Box>

                        <Box
                            component="form"
                            sx={{
                                '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                            }}
                            noValidate
                            autoComplete="off"
                            >
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Password" variant="outlined" />
                        </Box>

                        <Box
                            component="form"
                            sx={{
                                '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                            }}
                            noValidate
                            autoComplete="off"
                            >
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Confirm Password" variant="outlined" />
                        </Box>

                        <Button variant="contained" type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                    </Stack>
                </form>
            </Wrapper>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: In my case it was caused by a vite cache issue and I was able to fix it as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916125/5977966

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76017295/15330819

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by removing the node_modules/.vite/deps folder and restart the server.

After deleting the folder, run the following commands:

npm i --force and then npm run dev

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have tried to implement all solutions I found on Stackoverflow or Github but none of them solved the problem.

Then I replace all MUI `Box` components with MUI `Stack` components and it worked. As far as I know, MUI `Box` and MUI `Stack` components are like siblings. Both are made of the `div` element. The difference is the MUI `Stack` component has the `display flex` style on it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked, but oh man, the amount of weird obscure bugs in MUI that are hard to report and reproduce are making me question my tech stack..