# how to solve "Uncaught TypeError: createTheme_default is not a function" error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, vite

I am developing an application in react with vite, typescript and mui, but I keep getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHme.png)

seems to be related to material ui.

Sometimes it is solved by going to '\node_modules.vite' and deleting the 'deps' folder, then reinstalling dependencies. But eventually the same error appears again

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-clima",
  "homepage": "./",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "build": "tsc && vite build --base=/React-weather-app-apli-client/",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.14.3",
    "@mui/material": "5.14.6",
    "@types/node": "20.5.4",
    "axios": "1.4.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { theme } from "./theme/theme.ts";
import { WeatherProvider } from "./context/WeatherProvider.tsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <WeatherProvider>
        <App />
      </WeatherProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

theme.ts

```
import { PaletteColorOptions, createTheme, PaletteColor } from "@mui/material";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    typography: {
      fontFamily: string;
    };
  }
  interface Palette {
    purple: PaletteColor;
    gray: PaletteColor;
    grayLight: PaletteColor;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    purple: PaletteColorOptions
    gray: PaletteColorOptions
    grayLight: PaletteColorOptions
  }
}


export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Raleway"].join(","),
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#100E1D",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#1E213A",
    },
    purple: {
      main: "#3C47E9",
    },
    gray: {
      main: "#616475"
    },
    grayLight: {
      main: "#E7E7EB"
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Material UI createTheme\_default is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74542488/react-material-ui-createtheme-default-is-not-a-function)